# Color Coding days if they have multi-day events

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a monthly calendar, and I just want to change the color of a day if it has an event on that day. It works great with single day events, but for days that span multiple days, day_event_total only counts the first day. Code looks like this:

```
<td class="day_cell {if day_event_total > 0}has_events{/if}">
    {if day_event_total > 0}
    <a class="num"
        href="{path='/envelopers/community/calendar'}/{date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/">
    {/if}
    <div class="date">
        {date format="%j"}
    </div>
    {if day_event_total > 0}
        </a>
    {/if}
{if:else}
    <td class="day_cell out_of_range">
    <div class="date">
    <span class="num">
        {date format="%j"}
    </span>
    </div>
{/if}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the [{if event_multi_day}{/if} conditional](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/events/#if_event_multi_day) is only available within the [{events}{/events} variable pair](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/cal/#events). Color-coding events is easy this way, but color-coding days based on event data is not really possible.